# Large signal current measurements of a loudspeaker

Tags: audio, current-measurement, measurement, transducer

I'm trying to work out a method of measuring electrical current through a loudspeaker load for voltages in excess of +-20 V to be read by an audio interface - I need to scale down both voltage and current to manageable levels for the interface (i.e. within +-10 V).

I understand the methods for lower input voltages but using a small resistance value shunt in the case of higher voltages reults in large a current across the resistor. When using a 100 milliohm or 10 milliohm shunt, the power is acceptable as the voltage seen by the shunt is pretty small but I'm worried that those resistance values are too close to cable resistances.

I feel like I'm potentially missing something obvious.

One solution is to use an EMF current sensor but I'm trying to avoid this because of cost.

I'm looking to get a 40 dB attenuation, I've included my current working for clearer explanation.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about a 10 mohm (or even a 100 mohm) current sense resistor that's in series with the speaker leads impacting performance.  What's you speaker's impedance?  4 ohms, 8 ohms?

Comment: It's for a measurement and analysis system so driver impedance will vary dependent on unit. Yeah, I'm not concerned about small resistors impacting the performance really so much as wondering if small resistors, such as the values suggested, are viable for this application considering the inherent resistances of speaker wire and terminals etc. I might just be over-complicating things for myself...

Answer (score 0):

Your audio interface has balanced inputs (if it is a reasonably good one), why not use them together with a kelvin connected current sense resistor?

Boom, cable resistance stops mattering, and your 10mR resistor works just fine..

Comment: Thanks, seems like that could be a viable option! Hadn't heard of the Kelvin connection type shunts.

Comment: Doesn't OP want to measure the current through the loudspeaker load, which is not an input and is not balanced?

Comment: @SteveSh You connect his 'interface Zin' which I take to be an input to the sound card as a differential input across the current sense resistor kelvin style, then you do the same thing with Zin2 which is the voltage sense arm.